# Handling http 100 response with cURL/ pycurl (oauth 2.0)

Tags: python, curl, oauth-2.0, pycurl

I'm trying to authenticate a bot which posts on stocktwits ([see API](https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#oauth-authorize-docs)) with Python/pycurl. As I understand it, first I need to request that the application is authorized to use Stocktwits user data via `oauth/authorize`, which returns an authorization code. Then I need to confirm permission via `oauth/token`, which would send back an access token that can be used to post stocktwits.

The problem I'm running into is that after I make a post request to `auth/authorize`, the response returned is

```
Host: api.stocktwits.com
Authorization: Basic bmljay5vc2hpbm92QGdtYWlsLmNvbTp6YWRuaWsxMg==
User-Agent: PycURL/7.43.0.2 libcurl/7.60.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0h zlib/1.2.11 c- 
ares/1.14.0 WinIDN libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.32.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

and the program just stalls waiting. How can I handle the `http 100` response?

Code for api call is below

```
def get_auth_token:
    auth_data = ""
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.CAINFO, self.CA_CERTS)
    c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
    c.setopt(c.URL, uri_to_ouath_authorize_call)
    c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, auth_data)
    c.setopt(c.USERPWD, 'bot_account_username:password')
```

Comment: in `Authorization` header above you have your username:password base64 encoded (so basically clear text), if you forgot to modify it, I would suggest to delete this question and recreate a new one without the original values

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need to use `POSTFIELDS` or `READFUNCTION` to supply the post data, it doesn't look like you have anything for the request body configured. See https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POST.html.

Using `pycurl.POST` is a common mistake, normally `POSTFIELDS` should be used instead.